# Array search in multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have following multidimensional array :

```
    Array
(
    [entity_id] => 5740
    [parent_id] => 5739
    [label] => Sports
    [name] => sports
    [icon] => http://localhost/magento/media/catalog/category/
    [level] => 3
    [tab_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [color] => #555555
    [coordinate] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [amount] => 100000
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 5754
                    [parent_id] => 5740
                    [label] => Badminton
                    [name] => badminton
                    [icon] => http://localhost/magento/media/catalog/category/
                    [level] => 4
                    [tab_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 354
                        )

                    [color] => #DACC5C
                    [coordinate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12.9539974,77.6309395
                        )

                    [amount] => 75000
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [entity_id] => 5756
                                    [parent_id] => 5754
                                    [label] => Tournaments
                                    [name] => tournaments
                                    [icon] => http://localhost/magento/media/catalog/category/
                                    [level] => 5
                                    [tab_id] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 354
                                        )

                                    [color] => #8DCD55
                                    [coordinate] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 12.9539974,77.6309395
                                        )

                                    [amount] => 42187.5
                                )

                        )

                )
```

How can I perform array search on this to get the children array . I have dynamic value on the basis of which I want to search . 
Lets say I want to search for `[label] => Badminton` , how I can get that array ?
Please help me on this . Thanks.

Comment: You have to use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function search_recursive(array $children, $key, $value){
    foreach($children as $child){
        if(isset($child[$key]) && $child[$key] === $value){
            return $child;
        }

        if(isset($child['children']) && is_array($child['children'])){
            $found = search_recursive($child['children'], $key, $value);
            if($found){
                return $found; 
            }
        }    
    }

    return false;
}

$children = [$array];
$result = search_recursive($children, 'label', 'Badminton');
```

Comment: Looks promising, a fiddle will get you a good number of up-votes on this answer if it works as expected.

Comment: Really helpful , I got my result . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must search recursive:

```
function array_search_recursive($haystack, $keyToBeSearched, $valueToMatch)
{
  if (array_key_exists($keyToBeSearched, $haystack)
      && $haystack[$keyToBeSearched] == $valueToMatch
  ) {
    return $haystack;
  }
  foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      return array_search_recursive($value, $keyToBeSearched, $valueToMatch);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That's actually the only answer here that really works and which is not very hacky.

Comment: You did the same mistake as me. Each "children" array is a *list* of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

@vikas.badola.. I guess there is no such in-built function to fulfill your requirement. But you can write a simple function like:

```
function search_array($arr, $field)
{
    foreach ($arr as $data)
    {
        if ($arr['label'] == $field)
            return $arr;
    }
}

$badminton = search_array($data['children'], 'badminton');
```

Hope this might help!!!

Comment: And what if you wanted to get an element which is a child of a child? It's not the intention that you know the depth of an array when you pass it.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat .. Have you read the question, he has not mentioned the dynamic array of unknown depth, he has given an example array with which the solution is required!

Comment: Yes..I agree with you @ThomasDavidPlat. But the other people can answer using whatever they want to, so am I, but there is no such restriction that we need to used the methods what other developers are using that's why **stack is an open community**. I tried answering this question in my way, if you got an better answer just share it openly so that others can be benefited, arguments are not a better options always..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Same recursive implementation with example:

```
function recursive_search($arr, $k, $v)
{
    if (!is_array($arr)) {
        return null;
    }

    if (array_key_exists($k, $arr) && $arr[$k] == $v) {
        return $arr;
    }

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $found = recursive_search($val, $k, $v);
        if (!is_null($found)) {
            return $found;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$arr = array(
    'a' => array(
        'd' => 1,
        'b' => array(
            'c' => 2,
            'd' => 2,
        )
    )
);

var_dump(recursive_search($arr, 'd', 0));
var_dump(recursive_search($arr, 'd', 1));
var_dump(recursive_search($arr, 'd', 2));
```

prints

```
NULL
array(2) {
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["c"]=>
    int(2)
    ["d"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
array(2) {
  ["c"]=>
  int(2)
  ["d"]=>
  int(2)
}
```